# Clicking link inside div firing div's onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

I have this simple issue: a div that contains a link, and the div has an onclick function defined. However, when I click the link, I just want to follow the link, and not fire the containing div's function.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/3235/)

HTML

```
<div>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('div').click(function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

CSS

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

So here, when I click the div, an alert is shown: that's fine. When the link is clicked, I don't want the alert to show.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can apply `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` to the link. According to the API, this keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree (https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/).

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxrdrqrc/